# csvHelper Put values from different lines into one filed in Database

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a .csv file structured like so, first row is the header column, for each SomeID I need to add the NetCharges together(or substract if the code calls for it) and put each item into its own column by the SomeCode column.

Heres the file I receive;
SomeID,OrderNumber,Code,NetCharge,Total
23473,30388,LI 126.0000, 132.00
96021, 000111, LI, 130.00, 126.00
23473,30388,FU 6.0000, 132.00
4571A,10452,LI,4100.0000, 4325.0000
4571A,10452,FU,150.00,4325.0000
4571A,10452,DT,75.00,4325.0000

I need to insert the data to my sql table which is structured like this. This is what I'm aiming for:

ID    OrderNumber  LICode LICodeValue FUCode FUCodeValue DTCode, DTCodeValue, total
23473 30388n        LI    126.000     FU     6.0000      NULL    NULL          132.0000
4571A 10452         LI    4100.0000   FU     150.0000    DT      75.00         4325.0000

My SomeID will not always be grouped together like the 4571A id is.I basically need to iterate over this file and create one record for each SomeID. I cannot seem to find a way with csvHelper. I'm using C# and csvHelper. I have trid this so far but I cannot get back to the SomeId after passing on to the nexr one:
using (var reader = new StreamReader( "C:\testFiles\some.csv" ))

```
        using (var csv = new CsvReader( reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ))
        {
            
            var badRecords = new List<string>();
            var isRecordBad = false;

            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
            csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;
            csv.Configuration.IgnoreBlankLines = true;
            csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

            csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context =>
            {
                isRecordBad = true;
                badRecords.Add( context.RawRecord );
            };
            csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = ( s, i, context ) =>
            {
                isRecordBad = true;
                badRecords.Add( context.RawRecord );
            };

            List<DataFile> dataFile = csv.GetRecords<DataFile>().ToList();

            //initialize variable
            string lastSomeId = "";

            if (!isRecordBad)
            {
                foreach (var item in dataFile)
                {
                    // check if its same record
                    if (lastSomeId != item.SomeID)
                    {
                        MyClass someClass = new MyClass();
                        lastSomeId = item.SomeID;
                        //decimal? LI = 0;//was going to use these as vars for calculations not sure I need them???
                        //decimal? DSC = 0; 
                        //decimal? FU = 0;

                       
                        someClass.Id = lastSomeId;
                        someClass.OrdNum = item.OrderNumber;
                        
                        
                        if (item.Code == "LI")
                        {
                            someClass.LICode = item.Code;
                            someClass.LICodeValue = item.NetCharge;
                        }
                        if (item.Code == "DT")
                        {
                            someClass.DTCode = item.Code;
                            someClass.DTCodeValue = item.NetCharge
                        }
                        if (item.Code == "FU")
                        {
                            someClass.FUCode = item.Code;
                            someClass.FUCodeValue = item.NetCharge;
                        }
                        someClass.Total = (someClass.LICodeValue + someClass.FUCodeValue);
                        
                        //check for other values to calculate
                      
                        
                        //insert record to DB
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Insert into db after maipulation of values
                    }
                }
            }

            isRecordBad = false;
        }//END Using
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okay, so I sorted my list. Forgot I could do a simple Linq query to get it in the order I need sequentially to read. dataFile = dataFile.OrderByDescending( x => x.DocumentID ).ToList();

Comment: So now my list is sorted to iterate over and put everything in its right column:SomeID,OrderNumber,Code,NetCharge,Total 
23473,30388,LI 126.0000, 132.00
23473,30388,FU 6.0000, 132.00  
96021, 000111, LI, 130.00, 126.00 
4571A,10452,LI,4100.0000, 4325.0000 
4571A,10452,FU,150.00,4325.0000 
4571A,10452,DT,75.00,4325.0000